# Why is my Spring AOP within pointcut not working but execution is?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-aop

In my Spring Boot application I have working a pointcut against an interface that successfully works using "execution". I tried converting it to "within" as an exercise following a tutorial and it is not working and I can't figure out why.

Here is Service Interface:

```
package com.test.services;

import com.test.model.MyObject;

public interface MyService {
    MyObject get(Long id);
}
```

Here is Aspect that works:

```
package com.test.aop;

import org.aspectJ.lang.annoation.Aspect;
import org.aspectJ.lang.annoation.Before;
import org.aspectJ.lang.annoation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
    @Pointcut("execution(* com.test.services.MyService.*(..))")
    public void anyMyServiceMethod() {}

    @Before("anyMyServiceMethod()")
    public void beforeAnyServiceMethod() {
        System.out.println("HERE!");
    }
}
```

I changed it to this and it doesn't work:

```
package com.test.aop;

import org.aspectJ.lang.annoation.Aspect;
import org.aspectJ.lang.annoation.Before;
import org.aspectJ.lang.annoation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
    @Pointcut("within(com.test.services.*)")
    public void anyMyServiceMethod() {}

    @Before("anyMyServiceMethod()")
    public void beforeAnyServiceMethod() {
        System.out.println("HERE!");
    }
}
```

From what I read I thought the pointcut above using "within" should match any method in the package com.test.services but it is not. Am I missing something?

Comment: From my point of view, it should work... Can you please check it again to be on the safe side?

Comment: You didn't show how you're actually invoking your service. Do you have a self-call?

Comment: No I am not making a self call. I am aware that would not work. The service is being called from a RestController. The Service is Autowired into the Controller.

Comment: Some feedback to my answer would be nice. _(I will delete this comment again after the feedback will have arrived.)_

Answer (score 3):

Probably the class implementing `MyService` is defined in a package other than `com.test.services`, such as

- a subpackage like `com.test.services.impl` or
- a totally different package like `com.test.app`.

As described [Language semantics - Pointcuts](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/semantics-pointcuts.html) in the AspectJ documentation,

- some pointcut types like `execution()` or `call()` (unavailable in Spring AOP) deal with the runtime structure (match signatures),
- while others like `within()` or `withincode()` deal with lexical structure (where the matching code is defined). See e.g. [section "Program text-based pointcuts"](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/semantics-pointcuts.html#d0e5495).

So if we have a class `com.test.app.MyServiceImpl`, you can fix your pointcut to be `within(com.test.services.*+)` in order to also match subtypes of classes defined in the `com.test.services` package. The `+` for subtypes is not necessary in `execution()`, because `MyServiceImpl` is also a `MyService`, i.e. `execution(* com.test.services.MyService.*(..))` already matches.

If on the other hand the class name was `com.test.services.impl.MyServiceImpl` instead, the pointcut `within(com.test.services..*)` (double dot for including subpackages) would also work, but then it would again exclude implementations in other packages. The most universal one is `within(com.test.services..*+)`, but which one you use really depends on your use case, and too broad is not good either in many cases.